# Why can we GET the value of an object within an object, but not SET its value?

Tags: c++, class, object, templates

In the below code, I have created a very basic template class **Pair** and its 2 objects - p1 & p2.
I can get the value of data member ***x*** of object *p2* using `cout << p2.getx().getx() << p2.getx().gety();`.

##### Main Question:

If I can GET the value in this way, then why cannot I SET the value of x using
`(p2.getx()).setx('c');`
and
`(p2.getx()).sety(8.12);` ?

##### Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename V> class Pair {
  T x;
  V y;

  public:
  void setx(T x) {
    this->x = x;
  }
  T getx() {
    return x;
  }
  void sety(V y) {
    this->y = y;
  }
  V gety() {
    return y;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Pair <char,int> p1;  //Declared to put in p2
  p1.setx('b');
  p1.sety(12.23);
  
  Pair <Pair<char,int>, double> p2;
  p2.setx(p1);
  p2.sety(24.36);

  cout<<p2.getx().getx()<<" "<<p2.getx().gety()<<" "<<p2.gety()<<endl;
  (p2.getx()).setx('c');  //Here, p2.getx()!=p1, even though we set p2.x=p1. This is because p2.getx() returns a value/copy of p1 (an instance), not an object (or var).
  (p2.getx()).sety(8.12);
  p2.setx(p1);
  cout<<p2.getx().getx()<<" "<<p2.getx().gety()<<" "<<p2.gety()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What I think I've understood so far is that `p2.getx()` returns a copy of p1, and to make `p2.getx().setx(value)` work, I would have to make it return a reference to p1.
But still what I would like to understand is that if `p2.getx().()` doesn't work, how does `p2.getx().()` still work?

Comment: `What I think I've understood so far is that p2.getx() returns a copy of p1, and to make p2.getx().setx(value) work, I would have to make it return a reference to p1.` Correct. `ut still what I would like to understand is that if p2.getx().() doesn't work, how does p2.getx().() still work?` You get the x of the copy, why shouldn't this work?

Comment: @tkausl So does this mean that p2.getx().() is working in the background but there is no way to see it since it is changing the value of p1's copy? If it is so then is there a way to see the change in p1's copy?

Comment: `So does this mean that p2.getx().() is working in the background but there is no way to see it since it is changing the value of p1's copy?` Yes. `If it is so then is there a way to see the change in p1's copy?` It ceases to exist at the next semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your main question, your getx() method returns `a copy of x inside p2`, if you set value to this copy, will not affect `the x inside p2`. If you want to change `the x inside p2`, your `getx()` method should return a reference like this:

```cpp
T& getx() { return x; }
```

For this question: "But still what I would like to understand is that if `p2.getx().()` doesn't work, how does `p2.getx().()` still work?"

`p2.getx().()` doesn't work because you didn't set `the x inside p2` directly as I explain before. `p2.getx().()` works because the first getx() returns `a copy of x inside p2`, and the second getx() will call the getx() of the copy, so it works.

Hope I clarify clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The **p2.getx().()** works because you're returning a copy.
Let's say that I have a function that accept an integer value by copy `int functionX(int x)` and increments the value that it receives with `++x` and I'm passing an `int value_int = 50` to the function.
The body of `functionX` will be able to read `x as 50` because it's a copy of `value_int`. If you run`std::cout << functionX` and then`std::cout << value_int` you'll find out that the first line will print **51** and the second one **50**, that basically means that passing by copy creats problems only with the writing of an object not the reading. If you want to change values of an object inside a function you should pass it by reference  and in your example the first function should return a reference because your're chaining two calls

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).